# Why does the method with byte parameter calls the method with short, why not int?

Tags: java, primitive

```
class Practice {
   public static void aMethod (int val) { System.out.println("int"); }
   public static void aMethod (short val) { System.out.println("short"); }
   public static void aMethod (Object val) { System.out.println("object"); }
   public static void aMethod (String val) { System.out.println("String"); }

   byte b = 9;
   Practice.aMethod(b); // first call My guess:don't know? it is short but why
   Practice.aMethod(9); // second call My guess:int correct 
   Integer i = 9;
   Practice.aMethod(i); // third call My guess: Object correct
   Practice.aMethod("9"); // fourth call My guess: String correct
}
```

Why does the method called with byte (b) as a parameter calls the method with short?

Comment: Narrowest applicable type.  `short` is closer to `byte` than `int`.

Comment: Why would the compiler use an int for the parameter when it perfectly fits into a short? Just saves memory

Comment: Yes i thought  that too, that the reason would be from which type is closer, but i wasn't sure thanks @LouisWasserman. Damn and already -2 points oh well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java automatically chooses the best applicable method for your type.

In this case you are providing a `byte`, which is the smallest possible data type. The conversion for all data types would look like:

- `int` - Possible, direct conversion from `byte` to `int`
- `short` - Possible, direct conversion from `byte` to `short`
- `String` - Not possible, `byte` is no `String` (usage of parsing-methods is needed)
- `Object` - Possible, conversion from `byte` to `Byte` to `Object`

Java now automatically chooses the conversion to the **narrowest type**.

The conversion to `Object` goes in favor of `int` and `short` since it introduces a whole object, a huge overhead.

Finally `short` is chosen instead of `int` since it is **smaller**. A `byte` fits inside a `short`, which itself fits inside an `int`.

- `byte` - from `-2^(7)` to `2^(7)-1`
- `short` - from `-2^(15)` to `2^(16)-1`
- `int` - from `-2^(31)` to `2^(31)-1`

[image: Ranges of data-types]

(The difference is larger but then you wouldn't see anything in the image)